# Can I use Y / N when I'm prompted with Did you mean: [command]?

Tags: linux, terminal

I noticed that when you type a command slightly wrong it comes up with did you mean: command_name

e.g.

```
git staus
git: 'staus' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
       status
```

that seems to me like a cool idea to be able to go Yes and it does that command? I've tried but it didn't do anything so I was wondering if this feature did exist but with a different command?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion in your example isn't provided by [Ubuntu's shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87853/what-is-default-shell-for-terminal), but rather is part of the [`help.autocorrect`](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-1.html#Basic-Client-Configuration) feature built into Git itself.

There was [discussion last year](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-0-4-allow-recovery-from-command-name-typos-tp7531609.html) of adding an interactive "yes/no" prompt to Git, but some of the details were never decided upon so that work is still incomplete.

If you're looking for something to make this kind of suggestion for any command, you might like to try [using the Z shell (zsh) instead of Bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1577/moving-from-bash-to-zsh). It offers general-purpose spelling correction for both commands and filenames, and provides an interactive prompt:

```
$ ehco hello > test.txt
zsh: correct 'ehco' to 'echo' [nyae]? y
$ cat tesst.txt
zsh: correct 'tesst.txt' to 'test.txt' [nyae]? y
hello
```

Changing shells isn't something to take lightly, though. By using any non-default shell you'll likely hit a few road bumps that will require time and effort to resolve.

[Source from Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359005/how-do-i-use-the-did-you-mean-feature-in-ubuntu/359059#359059)

Comment: ah ok cool :) well I hope in the future it is added as this save so much time haha :) thanks again - will accept in a tick

Comment: I also recommend to you to set up aliases, e.g. in `~/.gitconfig` create an `[alias]` section with lines such as `st = status`. Then you can simply type `git st`.